# Flutter - Change background color of a widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

```
Widget _buildImageColumn() => Container(
     decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.black26,
  ),
  child: Column(
    children: [
      _buildImageRow(1),
      _buildImageRow(3),
    ],
  ),
);

Widget _buildDecoratedImage(int imageIndex) => Expanded(
  child: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      border: Border.all(width: 10, color: Colors.black38),
      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(const Radius.circular(8)),
    ),
    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
    child: Image.asset('images/pic$imageIndex.jpg'),
  ),
);

Widget _buildImageRow(int imageIndex) => Row(
  children: [
    _buildDecoratedImage(imageIndex),
    _buildDecoratedImage(imageIndex + 1),
  ],
);
```

The above code is taken from flutter website.

I want to change the background color of the widget with some animation (image). But after first tab, i don't want to execute the tap function again.

I tried to move `_buildDecoratedImage` to a statefulwidget and i can animate the particular widget and disable tap on that widget only. I am not able to disable tap on other three images (widgets).

though i can animate the background without moving `_buildDecoratedImage` to a statefulwidget and disable the tap of all the widget. But the entire screen is rebuilt.

Is there any way to achieve this without using streams?
One of the image must be tapped and animate the background and every image should not be tapped after that.

Please suggest the best solution for this.

Comment: Just use a bolean you can setTo true when user taps first time, then if its false your function will not get executed again

Comment: yes. but entire screen is rebuilt when i use setstate to change color of the background of the tapped widget

Comment: Yes the entire tree gets rebuilt. If you don't want that to happen, use BLOC architecture.

Comment: @KeertiPurswani Yes. I tried BLoC. BLoC is working. Is there any solution without using BLoC?

Comment: If you are using the conventional state management, I don't think it is possible. You could use `streamController` but that is basic Bloc itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use bloc plugin, you may want to consider using Stream to listen for changes in values set.

```dart
final _imageIndex = StreamController<int>.broadcast();
Stream<int> get imageIndex => _imageIndex.stream;

// Update image index
updateImageIndex(int index) {
  _imageIndex.sink.add(index);
}
```

Then to update, you can call `updateImageIndex(index)`. To listen for changes, you can set imageIndex on a StreamBuilder - this gets rebuilt when changes on Stream is detected.

```dart
StreamBuilder<int>(
  stream: imageIndex,
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      debugPrint('Image index: ${snapshot.data}');
    }
  }
)
```